# Future Tense OR Simple Present?

Tags: tense, if

Which sentence is correct?

> 1. If it's humid, the air will feel warm and wet.

> 2. If it's humid, the air feels warm and wet.

---

If both are correct, are there any differences in their meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather difficult question to answer because English grammar has slowly been evolving with respect to conditionals.

In speech and informal writing, both are acceptable and have equivalent meanings. In formal writing, it is still preferable to use

> condition (present tense) then consequent (future tense)

For example

> If I am in New York next Tuesday, I will come to the meeting

Notice in the example, it is a true conditional and refers to future events so the future tense in the consequent makes perfect sense.

However, your example is a conditional in form, but not in substance. In substance, it is a definition and true by necessity without regard to time. If I were your editor, I’d leave your tenses alone and change “if” to “when,” but I am a fussy writer.